# Convert Paypal cURL command to Axios request

Tags: node.js, curl, paypal, axios, paypal-sandbox

Following Paypal cURL command works as it supposed to be but unfortunately I couldn't convert  to axios code to work same. [Paypal Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/customer-disputes/v1#disputes-actions_send-message) doesn't have form data example but it allows that if you need to optional **message_document** file.

```sh
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/12345/send-message` \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer --token--' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F "input={\"message\":\"sample message\"};type=application/json" \
  -F "message_document=@sample.pdf"
```

I tried that Node.js code even without sending file but not successful:

```js
  const FormData = require('form-data');
  const form = new FormData();

  form.append('input', JSON.stringify({ message: 'sample message' }), { contentType: 'application/json' });

  const result = await axios({
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/12345/send-message',
    method: 'post',
    data: form,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: 'Bearer --token--'
    }
  }).catch(err => {
    throw new Error(err);
  });
```

I can't see that where is the problem. Please enlighten me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't expecting but it is solved with missing boundary information. These can be used:

```js
 const result = await axios({
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/12345/send-message',
    method: 'post',
    data: form,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}`,
      Authorization: 'Bearer --token--'
    }
  })
```

or

```js
 const result = await axios({
    url: 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/disputes/12345/send-message',
    method: 'post',
    data: form,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer --token--',
      ...form.getHeaders()
    }
  })
```